# deserialize string that was serialized with TypeNameHandling.All

Tags: c#, json.net

A class was serialized using the following sample

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Movie movie = new Movie()
            {
                Name = "Avengers",
                Language = "En",
                Actors = new Character[] { new Character(){Name="Phil Coulson"},new Character(){Name="Tony Stark"}
            }};
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Movie
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public Character[] Actors { get; set; }

    }

    class Character
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above sample produces the following json

```
{
  "$type": "ConsoleAppCompare.Movie, ConsoleAppCompare",
  "Name": "Avengers",
  "Language": "En",
  "Actors": {
    "$type": "ConsoleAppCompare.Character[], ConsoleAppCompare",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "ConsoleAppCompare.Character, ConsoleAppCompare",
        "Name": "Phil Coulson"
      },
      {
        "$type": "ConsoleAppCompare.Character, ConsoleAppCompare",
        "Name": "Tony Stark"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now,on another program **,that doesn't have access to the above models,**
I have to deserialize the string to an object but nothing I've tried seems to be working...

To create my new models I copied the json on my clipboard and used Visual Studio's "Paste Special" functionality

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleAppCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\nvovo\Desktop\asdf\aa.txt");

            Rootobject movie = null;

             // nothing Works :(
            //movie =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
            //movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None });
            //movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public Actors Actors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Actors
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Values[] values { get; set; }
    }

    public class Values
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Can I do anything about this or I should try to find the original classes?

**Update**

I don't care about the "$type" property.  It's not even on the original models. I just want to deserialize the JSON to a strongly typed model, including the collections (my real classes have more nested levels) but the auto generated types (using Paste Json) don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is to **ignore** the type information, then:

- If you deserialize with `TypeNameHandling.None`, then `"$type"` properties on *objects* are simply ignored will cause no problem during deserialization.
- But even with `TypeNameHandling.None`, `"$type"` properties for *collection values* cause problems because the type metadata generated for collection contains forces an extra level of nesting in the JSON:

  With `"type"`:

  ```
  {
    "Actors": {
      "$type": "ConsoleAppCompare.Character[], ConsoleAppCompare",
      "$values": []
    }
  }
  ```

  And without:

  ```
  {
    "Actors": []
  }
  ```

  When deserializing JSON with `TypeNameHandling.None`, if a serialized collection with the extra nesting level is encountered, an exception gets thrown.

  So you need some way to strip off the extra level of nesting during deserialization, e.g. with a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).  And in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166777/3744182) to the question [Strategies for migrating serialized Json.NET document between versions/formats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34162456/3744182) there is one already written and available for use: `IgnoreCollectionTypeConverter`.

Thus you can define your models as follows:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new IgnoreCollectionTypeConverter() },
};
var movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s, settings);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsjZJv).

Notes:

- `IgnoreCollectionTypeConverter` is designed to work with read/write collections, which is why I changed `Actors` from an array to a `List<T>`.
- If you need to **process** the type information rather than ignore it, you will need to create a custom [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm).  See [Custom SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) for details.  The question [How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19666511) gives a solution for creating a custom serialization binder that handles nesting of generics.

**Update**

You asked, *I just want to deserialize the json to a strongly typed model ,including the collections (my real classes have more nested levels) but the auto generated types (using Paste Json) don't work.*

During your development process, you can use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to load your JSON into memory, remove all `"$type"` metadata, and write out to a new JSON string.  Then, you can take that cleaned string and use it for "Paste Json as Classes".

The following extension method will do the necessary work:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    const string valuesName = "$values";
    const string typeName = "$type";

    public static JToken RemoveTypeMetadata(this JToken root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var types = root.SelectTokens(".." + typeName).Select(v => (JProperty)v.Parent).ToList();
        foreach (var typeProperty in types)
        {
            var parent = (JObject)typeProperty.Parent;
            typeProperty.Remove();
            var valueProperty = parent.Property(valuesName);
            if (valueProperty != null && parent.Count == 1)
            {
                // Bubble the $values collection up removing the synthetic container object.
                var value = valueProperty.Value;
                if (parent == root)
                {
                    root = value;
                }
                // Remove the $values property, detach the value, then replace it in the parent's parent.
                valueProperty.Remove();
                valueProperty.Value = null;
                if (parent.Parent != null)
                {
                    parent.Replace(value);
                }
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCialD) which takes your input JSON string and returns:

```
{
  "Name": "Avengers",
  "Language": "En",
  "Actors": [
    {
      "Name": "Phil Coulson"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Tony Stark"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.Unfortunately I have to process the collections. I'll try to reuse the existing model if possible or try your suggestions.

Comment: @NickVovos - *Unfortunately I have to process the collections.* - you mean you have to infer the collection type from the `$type` parameter?  That's kind of unusual.  The common use case is to infer the *object type* from the JSON and let the collection types be defined by the receiving system.   But if so can you edit your question to provide a [mcve] showing what you need to do?

Comment: @NickVovos - Or is your problem that you are trying to auto-generate types for your JSON using Paste Json as Classes and the `$type` information is messing things up?

Comment: Your last comment is correct.I don't care about the "$type" property.it's not even on the original models.
I just want to deserialize  the json to a strongly typed model ,including the collections (my real classes have more nested levels) but
the auto generated types (using Paste Json ) don't work

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you very much for your time!
It does what i want to do!